# How to extract plotted contours values list from matplotlib contours objects?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, contourf

I'm doing some contouring using the maplotlib.pyplot.contour and contourf methods.

After generating the contour lines/polygons, I want to extract the values associated with the geometries extracted using the `allsegs` method:

My code for getting the contour geometries:

```
def get_contours(grid_x, grid_y, krig_res, lvls):
    """
    Generate contours from krigged grid
    """

    cs = plt.contour(grid_x, grid_y, krig_res, lvls)
    csf = plt.contourf(grid_x, grid_y, krig_res, lvls)

    return cs.allsegs, csf.allsegs
```

The `cs.allsegs` call returns 8 lists of coordinates, so 1 list for each level, even if there is no geometry. The `csf.allsegs` call is only returning 7 lists of coordinates (my first level is empty so it is normal).

Is it possible to extract the level associated with each list of coordinates ?

Comment: `cs.levels` appears to returns the levels that have been contoured. I don't know if that list would contain the empty level or not

Comment: It looks like it contains all the levels that have been passed to the contour function (e.g.: I passed 8 levels. The `cs.allsegs` call returns 8 lists (1 for each level, with one empty) but the `csf.allsegs` returns 7 lists (the empty level is not there)